# Power Apps Pagination Not Showing Data and Delegation Warning

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm using Canvas for this this app. I've added a Table in Dataverse named AgenGenNewCases that is the dataset I'm using for this. It also has around 120K records.

I've watched this youtube tutorial on how to remove delegation warning and make use of pagination.
[PowerApps Gallery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKsNOsGj72A&ab_channel=RezaDorrani)

I'm using hidden gallery and another to just show the data just like what was created in the tutorial. Now I tried to recreate this

[image]

Unfortunately there's no data showing up. Page navigation are working properly for the buttons below but for showing the results itself it is blank. Not sure what step should I do next in fixing this.

On the bottom right of the pic, that's where my hidden gallery named **gal_NewCaseAgenHidden** that contains this code in Item property.

```
Filter(

          AgenGenNewCases,

          StartsWith('Policy Number', txt_policyNumberNewCase.Text)

          && ('Case Status' = drp_CStatus.Selected.Value || IsBlank(drp_CStatus.Selected.Value))
```

)

Now for the showing of data I have these code in the gallery named **gal_NewCaseAgenGen** which also has this in Items property.

```
If(

    ico_Next.DisplayMode = DisplayMode.Disabled,

    //For Last Set of Records

    LastN(

        FirstN(

            gal_NewCaseAgenHidden.AllItems,

            drp_Pagination.Selected.Value = varPageNum

        ),

        drp_Pagination.Selected.Value = (drp_Pagination.Selected.Value * varPageNum - Value(lbl_CountNewCase.Text))

    ),

    LastN(

        FirstN(

            gal_NewCaseAgenHidden.AllItems,

            drp_Pagination.Selected.Value = varPageNum

        ),

        drp_Pagination.Selected.Value

    )

)
```

You can also notice there's an object called **lbl_CountNewCase**, it only get the total number of rows in my hidden gallery.

```
CountRows(gal_NewCaseAgenHidden.AllItems)
```

I've followed all the steps mentioned in the tutorial, not sure if I'm missing something why **DATA is not showing**.

It is not shown in the picture but on the left of it there's a **DELEGATION WARNING** also in the **gal_NewCaseAgenGen**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On these lines:

```
drp_Pagination.Selected.Value = varPageNum
```

It should be:

```
drp_Pagination.Selected.Value * varPageNum
```

And it fixes the whole data set.